# Python, Pandas - перебор элементов с условием

Tags: python, pandas

updated
Привет! Помогите чайнику :) В процессе освоения Python и Pandas, столкнулся с проблемой применения к Series своей функции. 
Пытаюсь сделать функцию, которая будет перебирать значения заранее заданного набора чисел в Series и, в случае соответствия одному из нескольких критериев, осуществлять операцию с числом и вносить его в новый Series, иначе переходить к следующему числу.

Попытался на своем понимании построить следующую функцию, но она не работает (Jupyter просто уходит в бесконечные раздумия):

```
def trail_stop(high, low, close):
  for row in close:
    i = -1
    run = True  
    high.s = high.shift(i)
    low.s = low.shift(i)
    trail = (close + 0.0002)
    stop_loss = (close - 0.0002)
    while run == True:
      if high.s[0] > trail and low.s[0] < stop_loss:
        stop_loss = trail
        trail = trail + 0.0002
        i = i - 1
      elif low.s[0] > stop_loss:
        return stop_loss
        run = False
      elif high.s[0] < trail and low.s[0] < stop_loss:
        i = i - 1
      else:
        run = False

table['trail'] = table.apply(trail_stop(table.High, table.Low, table.Close), axis = 1)
```

То есть при таких исходящих данных (столбцы Close, High, Low) нужно получить на выходе следующее (столбец trail):

```
        High      Low    Close    trail
0    1.32396  1.32358  1.32391  1.32371
1    1.32392  1.32365  1.32365  1.32385 
2    1.32370  1.32364  1.32369  1.32389 
3    1.32378  1.32365  1.32371  1.32391 
4    1.32378  1.32360  1.32360  1.32380 
5    1.32390  1.32366  1.32370  1.32390 
6    1.32384  1.32370  1.32384  1.32364 
7    1.32386  1.32355  1.32380  1.32360 
8    1.32384  1.32358  1.32379  None
9    1.32389  1.32379  1.32387  None 
10   1.32386  1.32379  1.32383  1.32363 
11   1.32394  1.32360  1.32387  None 
12   1.32389  1.32370  1.32370  1.32390  
13   1.32390  1.32370  1.32390  1.32370 
14   1.32390  1.32364  1.32387  None  
15   1.32382  1.32373  1.32382  None
```

Буду рад любой помощи или совету куда копать. Спасибо

Comment: вы можете привести пример входного (т.к. `np.random` сгенерит случайные данные и мы не увидим вашего исходного DF) и выходного (результирующего) DataFrame'а ?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Понял, что ничего не ясно с предыдущего поста. Переделал и свою функцию и внес реальные данные

Comment: 1)  переменная `i` влияет на выполнение следующей строки. Не думаю, что это требовалось
2) опишите как вы видите выход из ветки:
      `elif high.s[0] < trail and low.s[0] < stop_loss:`
попав сюда цикл не закончится никогда, что видимо и происходит

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

1) У вас объявление run == True стоит внутри цикла, и тем самым у вас цикл ходит по замкнутому кругу. Попробуйте вынести его в первую строчку функции, над циклом.

2) Не уверен, что верно понимаю всю задачу, но, в качестве другого варианта, попробуйте использовать if вместо while.

Comment: Уточняющие вопросы к автору не следует задавать в форме ответа.

Comment: Бузу знать. Спасибо. Поправлю

Answer (score 1):

в вашем цикле есть ветвь `if` из которой вы никогда не выйдете, что и происходит при каких-то данных

```
  elif high.s[0] < trail and low.s[0] < stop_loss:
    i = i - 1
```